# Cakephp 2.4.5, partial json_encode output from Controller

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I dunno why, I have a similar script on another shared hosting and on my dev and this works fine:

```
public function admin_delete_entry() {

    $this->checkKey();

    $this->autoRender = false;

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Pronostic->id = $this->request->data('id');
        $res = $this->Pronostic->delete();
        if ($res) {
            $data = array('status' => 'success');
        } else {
            $data = array('status' => 'error');
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{"status"
```

I dunno why the output is truncated at this point... Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you compare the headers and post it?

Comment: First one (which works) http://pastebin.com/85S6EE9Y
Second one: http://pastebin.com/g2JRarBQ

Comment: `Content-Type` seems wrong, try adding `$this->response->type('text/x-json');` at the beggining of your action.

Comment: Still the same issue :(